# Jinja2: Create new row for every 3 items

Tags: flask, jinja2

Currently for every article in articles a new div with class span4 is created. 
Instead for each row I would like to limit it's content to three span's and create a new row once that limit has been reached. How can I best implement this?

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
  <legend></legend>
  <div class="row-fluid" id="main">
      {% for article in articles %}
      <div class="span4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
              <a href="{{ article.url }}"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/483CB4"></a>
              <div class="caption">
                  <h4><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h4>
                  <p> {{ article.summary }}</p>
              </div>
              <legend></legend>
              <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>
              <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Goal:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">article[0]</div>
  <div class="span4">article[1]</div>
  <div class="span4">article[2]</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">article[3]</div>
  <div class="span4">article[4]</div>
  <div class="span4">article[5]</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the built in [`batch` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#batch) to break up your list into groups of three:

```
{% for article_row in articles | batch(3, '&nbsp;') %}
<div class="row">
    {% for article in article_row %}
    <div class="span4">{{ article }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I better read through all Jinja2's documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, great solution, what if i want to show as 3 elements in first row, 4elements in second row, again 3 elements in 3rd row, 4 elements in 4th row, as alternate.

Comment: Then you'd need your own version of the filter - writing one isn't that hard, but the margin of this comment is too small to contain the code.  Write another question, with what you have so far. :-)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `loop.index0` and `loop.last` inside the `for` loop. Here is the [for-loop documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for).

Example:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
  <legend></legend>
  <div class="row-fluid" id="main">
      {% for article in articles %}
      {% if loop.index0 % 3 == 0 %}
      <div class="row">
      {% endif %}
          <div class="span4">
              ...
          </div>
      {% if loop.index0 % 3 == 2 or loop.last %}
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The `loop.last` clause should close the last row even if there were less than 3 items. `<div>` should start when `loop.index0` gives 0 as the remainder and should end when 2 is the remainder

Another alternative would be to group the items into rows before passing them into the template, then you can just issue two for-loops one inside the other.

Comment: This code-snippet helped me more than with batch(), thanks :-)