# Looping over items with Jinja, adding in div after every 5th item

Tags: python, loops, jinja2

## Problem

I have a list of 100 golf courses and I'm looking to insert a div, containing an image for an ad after every fifth course. How would I go about doing this?

### Update #1

#### content.html (Revised, newest version)

- I've updated my original code snippet because off of leovp's
  suggested edited below. I'm having trouble showing only `{% if content.featured == "Test" %}` and wondering how I should closing my if-else statement.

  ```
      {% for content in COPY.courses %}
              <div class="course course--featured">
                  <a href=""><img src="" class="course__image image--region"></a>

                  <div class="course__inner">
                      <div class="course__wrapper">
                          {% if content.state == "MO" %}
                              <p class="course__state">Missouri</p>
                          {% elif content.state == "IL" %}
                              <p class="course__state">Missouri</p>
                          {% endif %}
                      </div>

                      <div class="course__wrapper">
                          <a href=""><p class="course__name name--region">{{ content.name }}</p></a>
                      </div>
                      <p class="course__desc">{{ content.description }}</p>
                  </div>
              </div>

      {% if loop.index % 5 == 0 %}
      <div class="advertising advertising--inline">
          <div class="ad ad--rect">

              <div class="text-center hidden-xs">
                  <div id="fixed-leaderboard-region-top"
                      class="dfp-ad"
                      data-dfp-custom-pos="fixed-leaderboard-top, htf"
                      data-dfp-size="[728,90]">
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="text-center hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                  <div id="fixed-leaderboard-region-top-mobile"
                      class="dfp-ad"
                      data-dfp-custom-pos="fixed-leaderboard-top, htf"
                      data-dfp-size="[320,50]">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
  ```

#### content.html (Previous, old version for comparision)

- I've looked into using [`batch`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#batch) from this Stack Overflow [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797921/jinja2-create-new-row-for-every-3-items) that seemed similar, but I'm unsure if this solves my problem?

  {% for content in COPY.courses %}
  {% if content.featured == "Test" %}

  ```
  <div class="course__inner">
      <div class="course__wrapper">
          {% if content.state == "MO"%}
          <p class="course__state">Missouri</p>
          {% elif content.state == "IL" %}
          <p class="course__state">Illinois</p>
          {% endif %}
      </div>

      <div class="course__wrapper">
          <a href=""><p class="course__name name--home">{{ content.name }}</p></a>
      </div>
      <p class="course__desc">{{ content.description }}</p>
  </div>
  ```

  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While iterating, you can get the current index and check if it's divisible by 5:

```
{% set count = 0 %}
{% for content in COPY.courses %}
{% if content.featured == "Test" %}
<div class="course course--featured">
    <a href=""><img src="" class="course__image image--home"></a>
    [...]
    </div>
</div>

{% set count = count + 1 %}
{% if count % 5 == 0 %}
    <!-- additional content once every 5 courses -->
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

NOTE: This approach no longer works after version 2.10.

For detail see:
[How to increment a variable on a for loop in jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537439/how-to-increment-a-variable-on-a-for-loop-in-jinja-template)

Comment: Your answer is extremely close. With your solution, I was not able to get the ad to show up unless I close the first if statement `{% if content.featured == "Test" %}` before the `{% if loop.index0 % 5 == 0 %}`. But now, I see all 100-ish courses, when I want to limit it to those that have `Test`

Comment: I've updated the original answer to showcase these changes.

Comment: Ah. You need to check the index after some filtering condition. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Awesome. Yes that works. I was hoping you could explain some of your logic / reasoning here with the use of `{% set count = 1 %}` and `{% set count = count + 1 %}`

Comment: `set count = 0` creates a variable `count` and sets it to 0. Later, after the if statement allows us to continue, we increment `count` and check if it's divisible by 5. If it is, then we are right after the fifth / tenth / ... div.