# Using Jinja to loop over array add ad after every fifth golf course

Tags: javascript, python, loops, jinja2

## Problem

I have two templates that appear to look exactly the same, but on `branson.html` ads appear correctly after every fifth golf course, but on `ozarks.html` they do not. I've posted at the very bottom of this question what has worked as a solution from a previous [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866856/looping-over-items-with-jinja-adding-in-div-after-every-5th-item).

## What I've done

- I've changed the column type in Google Sheets, where the data is coming from, automatic to plain text
- I've even tried just copy and pasting the HTML structure from
  `branson.html` to `ozarks.html` and then just changing the labels
- I've made sure to `fab text update`
- I've made sure to check golf course object to see that `course.region
  == "Ozarks"`

### ozarks.html (Does not show ad after every fifth course)

```
<div class="featured">

    <div class="courses courses--featured">

        {% set count = 0 %}
        {% for content in COPY.courses %}
        {% if content.region == "Ozarks" %}
                <div class="course course--featured featured--region">
                    {% if content.featured == "Featured" %}
                        <a href="/courses/{{ content.slug }}"><img src="" class="course__image image--region"></a>
                    {% endif %}

                    <div class="course__inner inner--region">
                        <div class="course__wrapper">
                            {% if content.state == "MO" %}
                                <p class="course__state">Missouri</p>
                            {% elif content.state == "IL" %}
                                <p class="course__state">Missouri</p>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        <div class="course__wrapper">
                            <a href="/courses/{{ content.slug }}"><p class="course__name name--region">{{ content.name }}</p></a>
                        </div>

                        {% if content.featured == "Featured" %}
                            <p class="course__desc">{{ content.description }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>

        {% set count = count + 1 %}
        {% if loop.index % 5 == 0 %}
        <div class="advertising advertising--inline">
            <div class="ad ad--rect">

                <div class="text-center hidden-xs">
                    <div id="fixed-leaderboard-region-top"
                        class="dfp-ad"
                        data-dfp-custom-pos="fixed-leaderboard-top, htf"
                        data-dfp-size="[728,90]">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                    <div id="fixed-leaderboard-region-top-mobile"
                        class="dfp-ad"
                        data-dfp-custom-pos="fixed-leaderboard-top, htf"
                        data-dfp-size="[320,50]">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

### branson.html (Works fine.)

```
<div class="featured">
    <div class="courses courses--featured">

        {% set count = 0 %}
        {% for content in COPY.courses %}
        {% if content.region == "Branson" %}
                <div class="course course--featured featured--region">
                    {% if content.featured == "Featured" %}
                        <a href="/courses/{{ content.slug }}"><img src="" class="course__image image--region"></a>
                    {% endif %}

                    <div class="course__inner inner--region">
                        <div class="course__wrapper">
                            {% if content.state == "MO" %}
                                <p class="course__state">Missouri</p>
                            {% elif content.state == "IL" %}
                                <p class="course__state">Missouri</p>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        <div class="course__wrapper">
                            <a href="/courses/{{ content.slug }}"><p class="course__name name--region">{{ content.name }}</p></a>
                        </div>

                        {% if content.featured == "Featured" %}
                            <p class="course__desc">{{ content.description }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>

        {% set count = count + 1 %}
        {% if loop.index % 5 == 0 %}
        <div class="advertising advertising--inline">
            <div class="ad ad--rect">

                <div class="text-center hidden-xs">
                    <div id="fixed-leaderboard-region-top"
                        class="dfp-ad"
                        data-dfp-custom-pos="fixed-leaderboard-top, htf"
                        data-dfp-size="[728,90]">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                    <div id="fixed-leaderboard-region-top-mobile"
                        class="dfp-ad"
                        data-dfp-custom-pos="fixed-leaderboard-top, htf"
                        data-dfp-size="[320,50]">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

## Earlier solution

```
{% set count = 0 %}
{% for content in COPY.courses %}
{% if content.featured == "Test" %}
<div class="course course--featured">
    <a href=""><img src="" class="course__image image--home"></a>
    [...]
    </div>
</div>

{% set count = count + 1 %}
{% if count % 5 == 0 %}
    <!-- additional content once every 5 courses -->
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an easy fix.

On the `ozarks.html` template, it was using `loop.index` instead of `count` that was being set higher up to determine where the ads needed to be placed.